# Passar lista de números de cartesiano para polar

Tags: python, coordenadas

Estou com problema para passar uma lista de números que estão em coordenadas cartesianas (u,v) e preciso converter para coordenadas polares. Tentei pelo pacote cmath, da seguinte forma:

```
import cmath

cmath.polar(complex(media_v1,media_v2))
```

o nome media_v1 corresponde a variavel x, e media_v2 a variavel y.
Deu o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: complex() first argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer isto com uma lista de numero e não apenas com um número, cada variavel tem 360 valores de x e 360 valores de y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes utilizar a função `zip` para alinhar os valores de cada lista e efetuar a operação de conversão das coordenadas com os valores correspondidos:

```py
media_v1 = [20, 50]
media_v2 = [30, 60]
import cmath
result = [cmath.polar(complex(x, y)) for x, y in zip(media_v1, media_v2)]
print(result)
# [(36.05551275463989, 0.982793723247329), (78.10249675906654, 0.8760580505981934)]
```

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigada. Estou com problema agora pois com este código o angulo theta é gerado em radianos e eu precisava de um código que faça gerar direto em graus.